# Optimize upload/download speed to/from Dropbox using dbxfs

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using [dbxfs](https://github.com/rianhunter/dbxfs) on my Ubuntu server to mount Dropbox. The speed of copying a 100GB test file to/from the mounted directory is:

**Upload: 1.3MB/s**

**Download: 27.8MB/s**

My bandwidth is ~30MB/s both up and down. So, I am fine with the download rate, however the upload speed is too slow for me. Has anyone got similar or better results? I am looking for a way to optimize it.

Comment: did you ever improve your dbxfs upload speed? do you get the same performance with the desktop sync and web ui? i'm testing out dbxfs and getting slow upload speeds as well. there are a ton of threads on the dropbox forums with people having issues with upload speeds and most of the issues point to dropbox, so hoping there is a fix or setting to change

Comment: @zephyr707 no, couldn't improve it. Unfortunately...

Comment: thanks for letting me know. i've had greater success with rclone, but it has its own set of quirks (again seems to be issues on dropbox's side)